# Java Rx flatmap() and Java Ternary operator (?)

Tags: lambda, rx-java

I'm trying to replace use of Rx filter() operator via Rx flatmap() operator in following way:

**(Earlier using filter())**

```
    Observable.<String>just("A1", "A2")
    .filter(s -> s.contains("1"))
    .subscribe(s -> {System.out.println(s);});
```

**(Replaced via flatMap())**

```
    1. Func1<String, Observable<String>> func = s ->  s.contains("1") ?  Observable.<String>just(s) :  Observable.empty();  
    2.      Observable.<String>just("A1", "A2")
            //.flatmap( s ->  (s.contains("1")) ? Observable.<String>just(s) : Observable.<String>empty() )//   <--------- this approach did not work
   3.       //.flatmap( s -> { return (s.contains("1")) ? Observable.<String>just(s) : Observable.<String>empty(); } )//   <--------- this approach did not work
   4.       .flatMap(func) <---- this worked
   5.       .subscribe(s -> {System.out.println(s);});
```

This replacement worked only when I defined an explicit Func1 object at line 1. Lambdas defined on Lines 2 and 3 didn't  work. Only reason I can think of is that Java compiler is treating 2 and 3 as non value returning expressions but not sure why.

Can someone please suggest how can I use approaches on lines 2 and 3 ?

Comment: What were the compiler's error messages?

Comment: Both work for me,  type `.flatMap(` instead of `.flatmap(`.